# What is the best way of installing dotnet core on a raspberry pi?

Tags: .net-core, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, .net-core-2.0

This method

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david/2017/07/20/setting_up_raspian_and_dotnet_core_2_0_on_a_raspberry_pi/

leaves me with a problem... when I do

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dotnet --version
```

I get the following statement... and no version

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from: 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

If I do (as the link suggests) and use this protocol https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxdebian

then when I do the install step

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
```

then the package is not found.

Answer (score 10):

.NET Core distributions come in two variants. The *Runtime* and the *SDK*. `dotnet` figures out whether you want to use the Runtime or the SDK and dispatches your command to the right place.

The error you see is because `--version` is an SDK command [1]. `dotnet` tries to redirect it to the SDK, sees there is not SDK around, and suggests you install it.

If you have a `dotnet` command that seems to do *something*, chances are you installed it correctly already!

If you just want to see that `dotnet` works, try `dotnet --info`, instead:

```
$ dotnet --info

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : N/A
```

For Raspberry Pi devices, [only the Runtime is available](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md#net-core-on-raspberry-pi). The SDK, even if available, would probably be too slow and a bit too resources intensive to provide a good experience. So the suggestion is to use the SDK on another computer (say, Linux on Intel x86_64) to target the raspberry pi runtime (`dotnet publish -r linux-arm -c Release`) and then copy and run it on Raspberry Pi (`dotnet /path/to/published.dll`).

[1] I think it is completely silly and wrong. But such is life.

Comment: This is old info now. as of Sept 2019 you can build on the pi directly.